# How to find multiple different Webelements with Selenium that have the same attribute?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Lets say that the part of the webpage I am interested in looks like this in HTML:

```
<ul role = "tablist">
   <li>
       <button role="tab"> 1 </button>
   </li>
   <li>
       <button role="tab"> 2 </button>
   </li>
   <li>
       <span role="tab"> 3 </span>
   </li>
   <li>
       <button role="tab"> 4 </button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How do I construct a `Xpath` (or any other Suggestion you have) so that I can find all 4 different `Webelements` that have the attribute `@role='tab'`?

I am using Selenium with Java btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below `xpath` :

```
//*[@role='tab']
```

and use can use `findElements` that will return you a list and then you can iterate over the list as usual to get the inner context.

Sample code  :

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='tab']"));
    for (WebElement e  : list) {
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }
```